# adding a BORDURE page in Word , generated by apache poi in a maven project

Tags: java, apache, ms-word, apache-poi, frame

I've created a java maven application in which I use apache poi to generate Word documents as diploma. All works well, except that I did not find any documentation about adding a bordure for the page in word apache poi.

[image]

I use this code:

```
private void diplomas () throws InvalidFormatException, 
FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument ();
String landscape = "landscape";
changeOrientation (document, landscape);

// create header-footer
XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerFooterPolicy = document.getHeaderFooterPolicy ();
if (headerFooterPolicy == null) headerFooterPolicy = 
document.createHeaderFooterPolicy ();
// ....
// create header start
XWPFHeader header = headerFooterPolicy.createHeader 
(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT);
//....}
```

Comment: For me it is really unclear what is meant with "adding a framing for the page (framing found in graduates)". Can you clarify? Maybe adding a screen shot how this shall look like in Word.

Comment: I agree that this is unclear... Do you mean you want to put a border around the page? Could you perhaps tell us which commands you'd use to achieve what you want in the Word application, as a user?

Comment: oui, une bordure autour de la page, (c'était un problème de traduction)

Comment: I have a school management application, a button generates graduates selected students             private void diplomas () throws InvalidFormatException, FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
infoFormation ();
infoInscription ();
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument ();
String landscape = "landscape";
changeOrientation (document, landscape);

// create header-footer
XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerFooterPolicy = document.getHeaderFooterPolicy ();
if (headerFooterPolicy == null) headerFooterPolicy = document.createHeaderFooterPolicy ();
// ....
}

Answer (score 1):

From your beforehand question  you know body's section properties already. You know that there page size and orientation is set. There also settings for page borders and also page border lines are possible.

Unfortunately there is not any documentation about the ooxml schemas, the low level basic objects of `apache poi`, public available. So we need downloading the sources of [ooxml-schemas](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/ooxml-schemas/1.4/) and then doing `javadoc` form those to get a API documentation. There we find `CTSectPr` and `CTPageBorders`, which are page border lines.

Note `ooxml-schemas` version `1.4` is for usage together with `apache poi 4.0.0`.

Simplest example for creating a `Word` page having page border lines  set:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;

public class CreateWordPageBorder {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument();

  CTDocument1 ctDocument = document.getDocument();
  CTBody ctBody = ctDocument.getBody();
  CTSectPr ctSectPr = (ctBody.isSetSectPr())?ctBody.getSectPr():ctBody.addNewSectPr();
  CTPageSz ctPageSz = (ctSectPr.isSetPgSz())?ctSectPr.getPgSz():ctSectPr.addNewPgSz();
  //paper size letter
  ctPageSz.setW(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(Math.round(8.5 * 1440))); //8.5 inches
  ctPageSz.setH(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(Math.round(11 * 1440))); //11 inches
  //page borders
  CTPageBorders ctPageBorders = (ctSectPr.isSetPgBorders())?ctSectPr.getPgBorders():ctSectPr.addNewPgBorders();
  ctPageBorders.setOffsetFrom(STPageBorderOffset.PAGE);
  for (int b = 0; b < 4; b++) {
   CTBorder ctBorder = (ctPageBorders.isSetTop())?ctPageBorders.getTop():ctPageBorders.addNewTop();
   if (b == 1) ctBorder = (ctPageBorders.isSetBottom())?ctPageBorders.getBottom():ctPageBorders.addNewBottom();
   else if (b == 2) ctBorder = (ctPageBorders.isSetLeft())?ctPageBorders.getLeft():ctPageBorders.addNewLeft();
   else if (b == 3) ctBorder = (ctPageBorders.isSetRight())?ctPageBorders.getRight():ctPageBorders.addNewRight();
   ctBorder.setVal(STBorder.THREE_D_EMBOSS);
   ctBorder.setSz(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(24));
   ctBorder.setSpace(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(24));
   ctBorder.setColor("FF0000");
  }

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.");

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordPageBorder.docx");  
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```